# How to remove unwanted horizontals line in markdown

Tags: github, markdown

I'm unable to remove the unwanted lines in the markdown, In my GitHub profile README I have not used any horizontal line, but it's showing on its own, and I'm unable to remove it from the markdown.

**Here's the image**

[image: GitHub profile README]

GitHub profile README

**Here's the code**

```html
<h1 align="center">Hi, I'm Anuj</h1>
<!-- Social Media ICons -->

## **Connect with me ➜**

<div align="center">
  <a href= "https://twitter.com/anujcodes_25">
  <img align="center" src="https://img.icons8.com/stickers/100/000000/twitter.png" alt="twitter icon" height="40" width="40" /></a>&ensp;
</div>
```

As you can see, I have not added any horizontal line here.

#### I have tried various things which are

- I have tried to put the paragraph tag(<p>) inside the heading tag
- I also tried to give a line space, but it didn't work
- Instead of using the heading tag (from HTML) I have tried to use ## which is native to Markdown but still won't work

I have researched and tried my best to remove the horizontal line, but unable to do so.